# How can I check if a person, through an invitation link, has brought more people to subscribe to my telegram channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm using Telebot with node.js and create my bot.
In my bot, for each people, i send an invitation link about a Telegram Group.. i want the people, forward the link to friends and i want to check how many people join in my telegram group using that link.
If a person brought three friends to join, then I give him a prize.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, i'm not find a solution..

Answer (score 2):

You should set/get user ID in the link, like `t.me/examplebot?start=yourString`. When you start the bot with this link you'll get the text `/start yourString` so you can handle it.

As I know **you can't do this with group or channel link** so the bot can't read any parameters.